# Saving a specific value from a while loop in php

Tags: php, html

I have some work to do in computer science and I've been stuck for some time on something and I hope I'll find some help here.
(I'm coding in php)
So here's the problem : I have to do a list of items from a .txt file. So, in order to not write again and again the same code, I used a while loop to read the .txt data. The problem is, I want to make it possible to, by clicking an element of the list, going to another page that reads again the data from the txt. I don't know how to save the specific value of a moment in the while loop to make it accessible. May somebody help me please ?

Here is my php code :

```
while($n<$longueur){
                    echo('<div class="grid-item"> <a href="Fiche.php"><article>
                        <p2>');
                        lirefile($n);
                        $n=$n+3;
                    echo(' 
                        </p2>
                    </article>
                    <article>
                        <nav></br><img src=');
                        lirefile($n);
                        $n=$n+1;
                        echo('/></nav>
                        </br>
                    </article>
                    <span class="invisible.link"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>');}
```

Here's the lirefile function :

```
function lirefile($argu){
    $fp=file("data.txt");
    echo $fp[$argu];

}
```

So I would like to, if any item of the list is clicked, to redirect to a page where all the data corresponding to this item can be found.

Comment: `<a href="Fiche.php?id=something">` . I don't know what the `something` should be, because we know nothing about the data coming out of the file. Maybe it's just a line number, maybe it's some ID which could be extracted from the file. Maybe you can use `$n` for it.

Comment: What is a `p2` tag? Should that be `h2`?